# MaterialDesign-like reveal transition in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface

I'm looking for a *simple and intuitive* way to design CSS/JS view transitions as shown in this example in Goolges MD guidelines: https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B3T7oTWa3HiFZ3BiM1dnR0ZPU1k/animation_meanigfultrans_visualcont.webm

Is there any web framework or library which helps developing layouts with those transitions?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you can do, with more or less achievements:

1. use a div with fixed width/height and border radius 50% to get a ripple in the background. Then  animate the transition with transform:scale()
2. use a round clip path
   https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/
3. use Polymer by Google
   https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/

You could also use velocity.js to achieve events on animations completion.
http://julian.com/research/velocity/